# Oracle 12c can not connect to database from java app for some SID

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat

I now have an application work with oracle. After my oracle get upgraded to 12c then the weird behavior happen.

I can connect to oracle database when using SID=PRD1. But it's not work when I change it to SID=DEV

The error message is  ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol.

Both SID PRD1,DEV   can be connected successfully in Oracle SQL Developer.

But from java, Only SID=PRD1  is work and the SID=DEV is failed.

How can I solve this ?

Regards,
OBJ

PS . Both SID   DEV , PRD1  are in the same machine

Comment: "*No matching authentication protocol*" usually means you are using an outdated driver.

Comment: As I said , I can connect successfully with SID=PRD1  So I think the driver version is compatible.

Comment: So which driver version **are** you using?

Comment: I am using ojdbc14.jar.  And do not forget this driver can connect to 12c oracle with SID=PRD1  Thank you very much. I am now blank idea.

Comment: ojdbc14.jar is intended for Java **1.4** It is **not** compatible with Oracle 12, see the Oracle JDBC FAQ: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_01 You need to use a **much** more recent driver: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: I know that point , But I can connect to this when using other SID.

Comment: Is there any possible to solve this by oracle db server side?

Comment: Everything is same, Just change SID. then the error come up.

Comment: "*Is there any possible to solve this by oracle db server side*" - **no**. Use a driver supported for your database version.

Comment: *"But I can connect to this when using other SID"* So are PRD1 and DEV different database versions?

Comment: @APC both is same. IP server , port, user, pass all of these attribute are same.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_same thanks I will make a try.  But really wonder that if the version of driver is incompatible , it still be able to connect for some sid

Comment: Different databases can be installed using different versions of the database software. Let's make it easy: run this query on DEV and PRD1: `select * from v$version`. What results do you get? You may need a DBA to help you.

Comment: @APC  I have run select * from v$version.  Both return all same results.

`Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_same I have updated the driver to the latest version. Now it is work. But I still don't understand as the old version of driver can work with SID:PRD1.